# After deleting Main Storyboard.Add StoryBoard Programatically with Backward compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

My target for app is iOS 10.0As soon as I change my Target, I get a bunch of errors in SceneDelegate file. For backward compatibility, I added “@available(iOS 13.0, *)”  for Scene Delegate class.

I Started with  an OnboardingController. Which is totally programatic. So I deleted MainStoryboard and removed it from  ”Main Interface” and  ”Application Scene Manifest” in info.

Now, I have to set the rootView in both AppDelegate and SceneDelegate. If I don’t set window in SceneDelegate I am getting only Black screen in iOS 13.0+ Devices and if I don’t set in AppDelegate I get just Black screen in <13.0 Devices
**Since I am calling both files my viewdidload() in Viewcontroller is called twice.**

Following is what my AppDelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)



        let viewController  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navC") as! UINavigationController

        window?.rootViewController = viewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

Following is my SceneDelegate

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {


    var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
            guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }          
            window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
            window?.windowScene = windowScene

            let viewController  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeCollectionVC") as! HomeCollectionVC
            window?.rootViewController = viewController
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
...
}
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Highlight you exact issue.

Comment: Yes done.
Can you please check it out Thankyou.

Comment: As you said **If I don’t set window in SceneDelegate** you got black screen, but you are setting window with root vc, so whats issue in this?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited again. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be found easily by searching, but here is an example...

Note: reference to SO user [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt)

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

// entire class is iOS 13+
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene

        let viewController  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeCollectionVC") as! HomeCollectionVC
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }

}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window : UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?)
        -> Bool {
            if #available(iOS 13, *) {
                // do only pure app launch stuff, not interface stuff
            } else {
                self.window = UIWindow()

                let viewController  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navC") as! UINavigationController

                window?.rootViewController = viewController
                window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            }
            return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    // iOS 13+ only
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    // iOS 13+ only
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```